# Alerting the this.id keyword returns undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, inputbox

I create the same inputbox a couple of times dynamically. When a user presses enter it calls a function. I then test with this code:

```
function insertComment(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

But it keeps returning undefined. Here is the syntax I use to create similiar input boxes:

```
$("#divToAppend").append("<input id='testID' type = 'text' class = 'formatCSS' style = 'margin-top:12px ; ' placeholder = 'Add Comment' onkeydown='if (event.keyCode == 13) insertComment()'></input>");
```

Comment: Are you appending the input with same ID ? You need to know that there can only be 1 Id on each page

Comment: show us more code plz

Comment: in the event attrib, change insertComment() to insertComment.call(this)

Comment: Do you want to get the ID from the last textbox or from the textbox which is appended?

Comment: What  can I use if you cannot give the same id. I just need the value that is stored in the id.

Comment: TRY event.target.id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass this while calling    method :

```
$("#divToAppend").append("<input id='testID' type = 'text' class = 'formatCSS' style = 'margin-top:12px ; ' placeholder = 'Add Comment' onkeydown='if (event.keyCode == 13) insertComment(this)'></input>");


function insertComment(this)
{ 
alert($(this).attr('id')); 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it works, but in the alert it returns nothing as to saying undefined.

Comment: I think this serves the purpose

Answer (score 1):

Beware of `this`. It is a crazy variable and you always, always want to think twice before adding it in your code.

Before we debug, the first lesson is -

- Every function is always called in a context and if you can't tell the context, it is the `window` object.

Now let's breakdown what's going on here.

When a user presses a key on your input field, `insertComment` is called. Since there is no context, it is called on the window context. So now, inside the function, your `this` is actually pointing to `window`, and there's no `window.attr('id')` defined.

It is equivalent to calling `window.insertComment` where `this == window`.

If you modify your code like so -

```
onkeydown='if (event.keyCode == 13) insertComment(this)'

function insertComment(x){
    alert(x.attributes.id);
}
```

Here, the context will still be `window`, i.e `this` variable will still point to `window` object, but the `input` element itself will be passed as a parameter to the `insertComment` function.

`x` will refer to the element and you can now pull the `id` attribute in good old fashioned javascript way - `x.attributes.id`

(or in jQuery way, if you prefer - `$(x).attr('id')`)

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divToAppend">
  <input class="formatCSS" type="text" id="id_1">  

</div>
```

**js & jquery**

```
// For alert the ID
 function insertComment(id){
   alert(id);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
// Look for any event 'keydown' in any element which has a class 'formatCSS'
$(document).on('keydown','.formatCSS',function(e){

    // If enter is pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13){

        //Get the current ID
       var text_id=$(this).attr('id');

        //Split it to get the counter. The ID must be unique
       var id=text_id.split('_');

        //Add 1 to the counter
       var counter=parseInt(id[1])+1;

        // Build the new ID
       var new_text_id="id_"+counter;         

        // Then, create the new input with the iD           
       $("#divToAppend").append("<input id='"+new_text_id+"' type = 'text' class = 'formatCSS' />"); 

        // Last, alert the ID
        insertComment(new_text_id);


    }

});


});
```

Maybe it can help. :)

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/pN8P6/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the value in the ID? (it seems that part of your problem might be that you've got multiple identical ids, which is illegal.)

How about:

```
$("#divToAppend")
  .append("<input type = 'text' class = 'formatCSS' style = 'margin-top:12px ; ' placeholder = 'Add Comment'></input>")
  .keydown(function() { insertComment('whatever') });
```